# RMI bind object to Registry and access from Client

Tags: java, rmi

I am struggling with accessing a Remote Object from my Registry. I don't quite get how to access a binded object at the client. What i did is:

```
// export for RMI
IRemote remoteObject = new RemoteObject();
IRemote stub = (IRemote) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(remoteObject, 0);

// bind to registry so clients can find it
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port); registry.bind(bindingName, stub);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RMI**

*// Server*

```
// export for RMI
IRemote remoteObject = new RemoteObject();
IRemote stub = (IRemote) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(remoteObject, 0);

// bind to registry so clients can find it
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
registry.bind(bindingName, stub);

// unexport
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(remoteObject, true);
```

*// Client*

```
// lookup remote object on server
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, port);
IRemote remoteObject = (IRemote) registry.lookup(name);
```

Comment: No extraneous matter please. Just answer the question that was asked. The server's `Registry` variable needs to be static in practice.  You don't have to export the object if it extends `UnicastRemoteObject`.